# Bootstrap tags input not displaying the tags

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm struggling to get bootstrap tag inputs working, but I can't see what I could be doing wrong. As far as I can tell I've even followed the steps in this post [How to use Bootstrap Tags Input plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488382/how-to-use-bootstrap-tags-input-plugin)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="tags">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

*I'm seeing 2 things that are strange:*

**1)** The tags appear in the DOM but don't seem to have any sort of background applied so they appear invisible. But I can't see anywhere any mention of needing to specify a default color in the docs.

**2)** The control seems to resize it self as you're typing and putting in tags which I don't understand as it's supposed to have a fixed size.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Obviously I could add some CSS hacks to get the tags appearing, but my understanding was that it should just work out the box?

Comment: I think this is something you catch the CSS issue. For your use you can overwrite the color. `.bootstrap-tagsinput .tag {
    color: #555;
}`

Comment: @Sachink I could, and mentioned that in my question. But from my understanding I shouldn't have to? Which makes me wonder if I'm doing  something wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually like proving the bootstrap wrong:

> Because it looks like they have removed the support for *Bootstrap Tags Input plugin* after 3.3.7

The below snippet will work just fine:

```css
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
     width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="tags">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

when I removed :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

and added :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

*The background style started to appear solving your **first** problem.*

The second is actually `Bootstrap Tags Input plugin` default behaviour you can refer to this [link](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) which is their documentation page, in that you can see -

```
.bootstrap-tagsinput {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The above style comes from `app.css` which links from there example paths. This style is what keeps the `<input>` `100%` of its parent width. So if you want `100%` width you have to use custom style.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks that was useful indeed. I didn't dig into the CSS - though it does look like that's including v3 CSS for v4 JS. Wonder if that might cause other problems....

Comment: I don't think so in the case of `Bootstrap Tags Input plugin` but in v4 the CSS grid changes altogether. So, in my opinion, you better use custom style for `Bootstrap Tags Input plugin` and use **v4 CSS with V4 js**, and if you only need this plugin then for this plugin to work you don't need `bootstrap.min` file check my snippet.

Comment: @Ian one more thing that I forgot, only `twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7` work with the plugin, not the `bootstrap/3.3.7/`. I tried that also.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably give it a try over the weekend and see how I get on. Appreciate the help and the clarification at the end.

Answer (score 2):

**Here my observation:**
Bootstrap CSS is not loaded

1) Bootstrap 4.X in beta.

2) integrity attribute is preventing to load the bootstrap CSS

I have updated the code with a stable version of bootstrap

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" value="" data-role="tagsinput" id="tags">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set data in tags input like this:

```
$('#tag-input').tagsinput('add', 'tags data');
```

and then:

```
$('#tag-input').tagsinput('refresh');
```