# On enter key, form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap input tags like this

**myPage.html**

```
<form th:object="${field}" name="modal" method="post" th:action="@{/ajouterFieldEcran}">
 ...

 <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-12" value=""
            data-role="tagsinput" id="tags">
                </div>
            </div>


 ...
```

I get the example from this post [Bootstrap tags input not displaying the tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321407/bootstrap-tags-input-not-displaying-the-tags)

The problem is when I am typing the value and press enter to submit it in the input the form that is submitted.

Comment: You don't want to submit the form? or do you want to do something else?

Comment: i have a button that submit the form the thing that i want is : when the user insert a value in the input the input tags take it as a value

Comment: Any valuable example will be nice

Comment: better write demo using like http://jsfiddle.net/ to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable enter key in input tags like this

```
$(function() {
 $("input").keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
 });
});
```

put this inside your script tag

Remove `col-sm-12` from input class, you don't need that.

Also please note that you cannot use enter key in a text box for new line (input type='text' are single line by design), for multiline text you need to use `textarea`

Comment: the thing is that the value isn't displayed any idea why ?!?

Comment: You mean if you type any letter its not shown in the input box?