# Where could find an updated version of Bootstrap Tags Input plugin?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to implement a tag system and after search on google I have found  [Bootstrap Tags Input](http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) and I've tried to implement it but I am getting some errors.

After google about the errors with this library I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38488382/how-to-use-bootstrap-tags-input-plugin) that solved some of them.

As one can see in the picture below I still have some errors: [image]

I've checked inside the library and I have found that there are still work to be done. [image]

Does someone know where can I find an updated version of this library (without errors), or an equivalent plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bootstrap Tags Input` doesn't look like it's being actively maintained. That, and with Bootstrap 4 released, I can't really say its usage is recommended.

My personal recommendation is to look at [Select2](https://github.com/select2/select2) or, if that doesn't meet your tagging requirements, you can use the more specialised [Selectize](https://github.com/selectize) plugin.